# Why is pointer taking memory that is not assigned to it

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to learn Pointers behavior and I tried couple of examples.

From my understanding, "Program should throw error when we try to print the pointer while it is not assigned with the address of a value".

I wrote a block of code with pointer variables 'a' and 'b' and directly allocated value to pointer 'a'. I expected this would result in segmentation fault. Also the second pointer 'b' takes the address of pointer 'a'. Why do I see this behavior ?

Below is my Block of Code:

```
int *a;    // What exactly happens behind the scenes here ? What will "a" contain ?
int *b;    // Why does "b" take address of "a" ?
*a = 5;    // Why don't I get a segmentation fault here ?
cout<<a<<endl;
cout<<*a<<endl;
cout<<b<<endl;
cout<<*b<<endl;
```

And my output is,

```
0x246ff20
5
0x246ff20
5
```

Comment: _"Why do I see this behavior ?"_ - Simple, It's [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: you haven't allocated any space for `a` or `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Program should throw error when we try to print the pointer while it is not assigned with the address of a value".

In fact, when you attempt to use a variable whose value is not initialized, the behavior (i.e. what happens) is is [undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In this case, this means that your program *could* crash with a segmentation fault, or it *could* print something vaguely meaningful.  (Or [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) :-) )

What you are probably seeing is some values that happen to be in the memory locations that *now* correspond to those variables.  Those values most likely got there because somewhere earlier in the execution the memory locations were used for something else.

Comment: Nitpick; in the language of the standard, "unspecified" means something different: `use of an unspecified value, or other behavior where this International Standard provides two or more possibilities and imposes no further requirements on which is chosen in any instance`.

Comment: @Hurkyl - fixed.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of undefined behaviour there.

int* a;

What is contained in a? Undefined. Completely up to the compiler. In this case it seems to default to 0x246ff20. Why do I say that? Because `b` is also set to this. You can't rely on this and it may just be coincidence.

It just so happens that the value seems to be valid (pointing to a data page in memory), which doesn't throw a seg fault when written to.

That also answers the rest of your questions. The behaviour you observe is completely undefined.

You should be pointing your pointers to something. For instance:

```
int a = 5;
int* pA = &a;
int* pB = pA;
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything in C/C++ has a value by default. That value, however, is completely undefined.

Some OS-compiler combinations might zero it (ie, make your pointers null pointers), some might insert debug 'messages' into them (like [baadf00d](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_debug_values)), but most merely leave whatever was previously in the memory there.

Whatever the case of what is in those values, they will be treated by the compiler as if you did define them. Accessing undefined values is "legitimate" within C/C++ in the sense it is not explicitly disallowed, but not a good thing to do. Some compilers possess warning flags which will tell you if you are using an uninitialized variable, but these are not always foolproof, as it can be difficult for compilers to determine when some variables are initialized.

Whenever you define a value, you should give it a default value. For pointers, that would be `NULL` or `nullptr`. In more complex situations, where a "zero-value" might be legitimate (like the number of child objects to an object), you may wish to use a second variable, such as `bool initialized`, to store if the values are legitimate or junk.

De-referencing an undefined pointer like you are doing, much less *writing* to it like you are, will probably be caught by the OS and result in your program being killed for memory access violations. I'm somewhat surprised you got *any* output.

Comment: Usually not a good thing to do?  I can't think of any scenario where it would be a good thing to do :)

Comment: Given the C++ tag, you should recommend `nullptr`, not `NULL`.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I can think of a few where it would be a "good" thing to do, but usually not for any good reason. Like trying to sniff out memory left behind by other processes or (only realistic option on most modern OSes) trying to find memory previously used by the same process, for nefarious reasons.

Comment: @Hurkyl If I'm not mistaken, `nullptr` is only C++11 or compiler-extension.

Comment: Although I suppose it's more using intentionally-invalid pointers in the situation I described than using undefined ones. I can't really think of an example of using *undefined* values.

Answer (score 0):

`int *a;` is a pointer that may refer to every where!

when we can use of it that we assign a address to that or create a new of that, for example :

```
int *a;           
int *b = a;          // b variable is pointing to a variable (if *a changeed, *b also changed that value)
```

example 2 :

```
int *a = new int(5);     // a is a variable that allocate a 4 byte memory to it and its first value is 5

cout<<a<<endl;       // physycal address of 'a' variable is print
cout<<*a<<endl;      // value of 'a' variable (that is in 'a' address) is print
```

Answer (score 0):

A handy little tip, when using pointers, always set the pointer to null before you set it to a value, this way you always know that the pointer isn't pointing an obscure memory address or pointing to the same thing as another pointer.

And always use delete after using dynamic pointers